# Multiple CameraInfoManagers in same node?

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like this ought to be possible (https://github.com/ros-industrial/human_tracker/blob/master/packages/aravis_camera_driver/src/nodes/basler_multi_node.cpp shows an example though there is a lot going on)- but when I try to do it the set_camera_info topics are colliding:

```
 Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/set_camera_info]
```

Should the name parameter passed into CameraInfoManager(nh, "foo") be putting the /set_camera_info into /foo/set_camera_info ?

This is Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199387/multiple-camerainfomanagers-in-same-node?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have two cameras in your driver both cameras should publish to separate topics, e. g.

```
/stereo_camera/left/image_raw
/stereo_camera/left/camera_info
/stereo_camera/right/image_raw
/stereo_camera/right/camera_info
```

Now you can have 2 camera info managers in the same driver node for both cameras; but the 2 camera info managers should be remapped to separate topic, identical with the camera namepaces

E. g.
first camera info manager for left camera

```
/stereo_camera/left/set_camera_info
```

second camera info manager for right camera

```
/stereo_camera/right/set_camera_info
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) on 2017-05-30**:
Hey, might I ask you to provide more information about the implementation of your answer [here?](http://answers.ros.org/question/262840/how-to-implement-multiple-camerainfomanagers-in-same-node/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [NodeHandle used to construct](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#a8944fe301b12d38ed33ac6ccb3d9b63b) each CameraInfoManager instance needs to specify the correct subordinate namespace for that device.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) on 2017-05-30**:
Hey, might I ask you to provide more information about the implementation of your answer [here?](http://answers.ros.org/question/262840/how-to-implement-multiple-camerainfomanagers-in-same-node/)